# Can't unescape escaped string with ABAP

Tags: sapui5, abap

I want to escape this string in SAPUI5 like this.

```
var escapedLongText = escape(unescapedLongText);
```

String (UTF-8 quote, space, Unicode quote)

> " “

Escaped string

> %22%20%u201C

I want to unescape it with this method, but it returns empty. Any ideas?

```
DATA: LV_STRING TYPE STRING.

LV_STRING = '%22%20%u201C'.

CALL METHOD CL_HTTP_UTILITY=>UNESCAPE_URL
  EXPORTING
   ESCAPED   = LV_STRING
RECEIVING
    UNESCAPED = LV_STRING.
```

Comment: How are you escaping `" “`? When I escape `" “` using `cl_http_utility=>escape_url` it returns `%22%20%e2%80%9c`.

Comment: I do this in SAPUI5, unfortunately.

Comment: Actually, your comment helped me a lot in solving the problem, andreas! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the code in SAPUI5 to the following:

```
var escapedLongText = encodeURI(unescapedLongText);
```

This results in: (like andreas mentioned)

> %22%20%e2%80%9c

If I want to decode it later in SAPUI5, it can be done like this:

```
var unescapedLongText = unescape(decodeURI(escapedLongText));
```

The unescape needs to be done, because commas (for example) don't seem to be decoded automatically.